# Finding Laurent series representation of rational function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question regarding an exercise that is concerned with a Laurent series expansion.

[image]

**This is my solution for a):**

Consider the annuli
$$
A_1:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0<|z-1|<2  \} \\
A_2:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid 0<|z+2i|<2 \}.   
$$

We have,
$$
|-2i-1|
=|2i+1|
=\sqrt{5}
>2.
$$
So $1 \notin A_2, \ -2i \notin A_1$.

Consider
$$
f(z)
=\frac{5}{z^2+(2i-1)z-2i}
=\frac{5}{(z+2i)(z-1)}
$$
and
$$
f_1: A_1 \to \mathbb{C}, \ g(z)=\frac{5}{z+2i}=(z-1) f(z) \\
f_2: A_2 \to \mathbb{C}, \ h(z)=\frac{5}{z-1}=(z+2i) f(z).  
$$

By the above discussion, $g$ and $h$ are holomorphic on their respective domains as they have no singularities. By the Laurent series theorem we obtain the representations
$$
f_1(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a^{(1)}_n (z-1)^n
$$
$$
f_2(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a^{(2)}_n (z+2i)^n,
$$
where
$$
a^{(1)}_n
=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z-1|=\rho_1}  \frac{f_1(z)}{(z-1)^{n+1}}
$$
$$ 
a^{(2)}_n
=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z+2i|=\rho_2} \frac{f_2(z)}{(z+2i)^{n+1}},
$$
with $0<\rho_i<2, \ i=1,2$. From this we obtain the representations
$$
f(z)
=\frac{f_1(z)}{z-1}
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a^{(1)}_n (z-1)^{n-1} 
$$

$$
f(z)
=\frac{f_2(z)}{z+2i}
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a^{(2)}_n (z+2i)^{n-1}.
$$

on $A_1,A_2$ respectively. Using the substitution $k=n-1$ we obtain

$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a^{(1)}_{k+1} (z-1)^k 
$$

$$
f(z)
=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} a^{(2)}_{k+1} (z+2i)^k.
$$

By defining $a_k:=a^{(1)}_{k+1}, b_k:=a^{(2)}_{k+1}$, we obtain the Laurent Series for $f$ around $1$ and $-2i$. q.e.d.

However, I am not entirely satisfied with this. Considering the wording of b) I think I am supposed to find a more explicit formula for the Laurent Series. But how does one derive a more explicit formula in this case? The only thing I was able to observe is that $f$ has poles at the singularities, therefore the Laurent Series expansions should have finite principal part. But I do not see how this helps.

Comment: Do a partial fraction decomposition. One of the summands can be expanded as a Taylor series, the other will be in Laurent series form already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have$$f(z)=\frac{1-2 i}{z-1}-\frac{1-2 i}{z+2 i}.$$Note that, if $|z-1|<\sqrt5$, then\begin{align}\frac{1-2i}{z+2i}&=\frac{1-2i}{2i+1+(z-1)}\\&=\frac{1-2i}{1+2i}\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{z-1}{1+2i}}\\&=\frac{1-2i}{1+2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(1+2i)^n}(z-1)^n,\end{align}since $\left|\frac{z-1}{1+2i}\right|<1$. So, near $1$, the Laurent series of $f(z)$ is$$\frac{1-2i}{z-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-2i)(-1)^n}{(1+2i)^{n+1}}(z-1)^n.$$In particular, $\operatorname{res}_{z=1}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=1-2i$.

Also, you have, near $-2i$,\begin{align}\frac{1-2i}{z-1}&=\frac{1-2i}{-1-2i+z+2i}\\&=\frac{-1+2i}{1+2i}\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{z+2i}{1+2i}}\\&=(-1+2i)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z+2i)^n}{(1+2i)^{n+1}},\end{align}and so the Laurent series of $f(z)$ near $-2i$ is$$-\frac{1-2i}{z+2i}+(-1+2i)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z+2i)^n}{(1+2i)^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Is the computation of the Laurent series near $-2i$ actually correct? You seem to have a series of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z \textbf{-} 2i)^n$ which seems to be a series around $2i$. Shouldn't it be a series of the form $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n (z+2i)^n$? In fact, I got $(1-2i) 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-1}{(1+2i)^{n+1}} (z+2i)^n 
-\frac{1-2i}{z+2i} $ as a result.

Comment: Right you are! Sorry about that. I've edited my answer.